# Animate aspect ratio in D3.js?

Tags: mobile, d3.js, treemap

I am using the treemap example http://bl.ocks.org/4063582

I want to respond to orientation change on mobile devices by animating the cells of the treemap to fit the new aspect ratio. This is my non-working attempt:

```
  d3.select("#rotate").on("click", function(){
    alert('rotate');

    div.style('width', height+'px').style('height', width+'px');

    treemap.size([height, width]);

    var tmp = width;
    width = height;
    height = tmp;

    node
        .transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .call(position);
  });
```

My test button fires the alert but nothing happens in the treemap. Is this possible to do with treemaps?